# Is the OBB expansion file downloaded every update, even if it doesn't change?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I had a user complaining that the automatic Android update was downloading the entire app (140 MB download, including APK file and main OBB file) during an Android update. Is this possible?

I thought only the APK was downloaded during an app update - if there were no changes in the OBB file and the OBB file stayed the same -  same name, version and content.

This might be a Play Store bug, I noticed this when I was downloading my app the other day. The APK is 12 MB, but the % progress display number (not the progress bar, but the number that is displayed on the left side) went from 0 to 140 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OBB is not in your device, it gets downloaded.

If the OBB is in your device, and it has the same file size and name, it does not get downloaded.

If the OBB is in your device, and it has a different file size and same name, it gets downloaded and temp. gets appended to the file name.

Same happens with the patch file.